# How do you say to “bear in mind” or to always “keep in mind” in Latin?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, meaning

Self explanatory question. 
Okay so I know the word ‘remember’ in Latin is ‘memento.’ but I heard that there are different variations like meminero or something, but is there a way to say “to keep in mind” or “bear in mind” keep it in your head and remember or etc.

I looked around the forums but all I got was ’meminisse’ but I don’t know if that’s correct.

And would it be different if you added an ‘always?’ 
Like ALWAYS keep in mind and etc.

The translation that I got was “semper meminisse” is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question!

Answer (score 2):

The phrases used in Scholastic latin to convey something like "bear in mind", "take note" et sim. are e.g. the following (in late Latin freely with "quod" rather than acc+inf):

- Adverte... (as in: "Adverte tamen..." "But note that..."
- Advertendum est... ("One should be aware that..."
- Nota... ("Note that..." - weaker than "adverte")
- Nota bene... ("Take note...", "Bear in mind" - perhpas the best fit)
- Notandum est... ("It is worth noticing that...")
- Intelligendum est ("One needs to understand that...")
- Sciendum est... ("One should know that...")

Answer (score 1):

Unlike English, in Latin you have to specify more information when using verbs. (More alike to French or Spanish.)

**Memento** is singular imperative, as when addressing someone telling him to bear something in mind, as in *John, remember to turn the lights off*

**Mementote** is the plural imperative, like the previous, but addressed to more than one person, *Kids, remember to call your mom when you arrive*

**Meminisse** is the infinitve, *to remeber*

There are tens of other forms depending on the tense and the person remembering: **memini**–*I remember*, **meminerat**–*he/she remembered*, etc. (see all possible forms [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/memini#Conjugation))

Regarding the adverb *always*, **semper** is fine. Word order is more or less free in Latin, hence:

> **Memento mihi semper**

Is an acceptable translation for *Always remember me*.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure about "mihi" in "memento mihi semper"? For close, personal/ emotional relationships the genitive is used: "memento mei pro hoc et ne deleas miserationes meas quas feci in domo Dei et in caerimoniis eius."  (Nehemiah 13.14) = "Remember me my God concerning this and wipe out not my good deeds that I have done for the House of God, and for the offices thereof."

Answer (score 1):

Under [*mens*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=mens), Lewis and Short give an example using *in mentem venire* for "to come [in]to mind".  I would expect *in mente habere* and *in mente tenere* would both be understood.

Lewis and Short also give *in mente* with a dative of possession, specifically *in mente est mihi dormire* for "I have it in mind to sleep".  So I suspect *in mente mihi*, *in mente tibi*, etc., would also sound natural.

Also note that the ancients associate the mind with the heart and the chest, so *in corde* and *in pectore* would have similar meanings.  In particular, *in pectore* is used in the Catholic church to indicate appointments that the Pope already has in mind but that he has not yet announced.  (For example, he might announce on 3/31/20 that he created a cardinal *in pectore*.  When he finally announces who that person is, his order of precedence dates from 3/31/20.)  This is often done to avoid reprisals when the pope wants to appoint a cardinal who is currently in an unfriendly locale.

Answer (score 1):

Rafael's "memento mihi semper." may be worthy of further study. In a discussion on "indirect objects with transitive verbs" Allen & Greenough (p362; reprint p225) give the example "equo ne credite" (Aen. II. 48) = "put not your trust in the horse"; which appears to support the use of "mihi" (the dative) as an indirect object, coupled with a transitive, imperative verb. (A & G give "credo" as able to function as both a transitive and intransitive verb.)

The problem is that the sentiment expressed: "Always remember me." is something that would be said by a partner in, or about to leave, an emotional relationship. Again, Allen & Greenough (p350; p218): "Memini takes the genitive when it means to be mindful or regardful of a person or thing, to think of somebody or something (often with special interest or warmth of feeling):

"nec me meminisse pigebit Elissae, dum memor ipse mei" (Aen. IV. 335) =

"nor shall I feel regret at the thought of Elissa, so long as I remember myself.""

At the opposite end of the relationship spectrum, a casual acquaintance (A & G same page): "Memini takes the accusative when it has the literal sense of retaining in the mind what one has seen, heard or learned. Hence the accusative is used of persons whom one remembers as acquaintances, or of things which one has experienced:

"Cinnam memini" (Phil. v. 17) = "I remember Cinna.""

The accusative (casual acquaintances), the genitive (emotional relationships) but (A & G) do not offer any examples of "memini" plus the dative. Therefore, what is to be made of "Memento mihi semper"?